Does the Sequence formed by Intersecting Angle Bisector in a Pentagon converges?
Now asked on MO here.

Given a non-regular pentagon $A_1B_1C_1D_1E_1$ with no two adjacent angle having a sum of 360 degrees, from the pentagon  $A_nB_nC_nD_nE_n$ construct the pentagon  $A_{n+1}B_{n+1}C_{n+1}D_{n+1}E_{n+1}$ as follows:

$A_{n+1}$ is the intersection between the angle bisector of $\angle
   C_n $ and $\angle D_n$.
$B_{n+1}$ is the intersection between the angle bisectors of $\angle D_n$ and $\angle E_n$.
$C_{n+1}$ is the intersection between the angle bisectors of $\angle E_n$ and $\angle A_n$.
$D_{n+1}$ is the intersection between the angle bisectors of $\angle A_n$ and $\angle B_n$.
$E_{n+1}$ is the intersection between the angle bisectors of $\angle B_n$ and $\angle C_n$.

(the two opposite angles)

The reason why I chose this construction is that the point $A_{n+1}$ is the only point that doesn't  depend on $A_n$. I am allowing self-intersecting polygons in this constructions.

My question is if this process is repeated indefinitely would the sequences ${A_n}$
, ${B_n}$
, ${C_n}$ , $D_n $ and $E_n$
converge ?
There are only four possible scenarios:

The points will converge.
The points will eventually trapped  on a loop.
The points will diverge completely.
Two or more points coincide, or two adjacent angle have a sum of 360 degrees ending the sequence.

I tried to draw the first few pentagons to  see if the point will converge or not.


Here is the first 50 pentagons in a zoom-in animation:

I conjecture that the sequences converge to a single point for all non-regular pentagons. If convergence occurs, how can we determine the limit point based on the initial pentagon? If the limit point exist what interesting properties does it have for the pentagon?

Here is a Geogebra file that have the first 50 pentagons.

This is a python code than can calculate $A_n, B_n , C_n ,D_n ,E_n$
import math


print("Number of pentagons")
n=int(input() )
m=max(n,50)
m= min(m, 200)
from decimal import Decimal
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = m
Decimal(10)**(-m)


# enter your coordinates here
A=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
B=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
C=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
D=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
E=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]

print("Enter the coordinates of A_1")
A[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
A[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of B_1")
B[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
B[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of C_1")
C[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
C[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of D_1")
D[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
D[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of E_1")
E[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
E[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
X=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
Y=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
Z=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
W=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
T=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]

#defining some useful functions--------------------------------------------
def v(a,b):
    result= [b[0]-a[0], b[1]-a[1]]
    return result 
def crs(a, b):
    result = [-Decimal(0.5)*((Decimal(a[0]*b[1])-Decimal(a[1]*b[0])))]
    return result
def dis(a,b):
    result =[Decimal(math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2))]
    return result 




for i in range (2,n+1):
    AB= dis(A,B)[0]
    BC= dis(B,C)[0]
    CD= dis(C,D)[0]
    DE= dis(D,E)[0]
    EA= dis(E,A)[0]



    #Here to calculate A_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   CD*crs(v(D,C),v(D,E))[0]
    y=  -CD*crs(v(E,D),v(E,B))[0]+  2*DE*crs(v(C,B),v(C,D))[0]
    z=  -CD*crs(v(C,B),v(C,E))[0]+  2*BC*crs(v(D,C),v(D,E))[0]
    t=   CD*crs(v(C,B),v(C,D))[0]
    X[0]=(x *B[0]+y*C[0]+z*D[0]+t*E[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    X[1]=(x *B[1]+y*C[1]+z*D[1]+t*E[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    #Here to calculate B_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   DE*crs(v(E,D),v(E,A))[0]
    y=  -DE*crs(v(A,E),v(A,C))[0]+  2*EA*crs(v(D,C),v(D,E))[0]
    z=  -DE*crs(v(D,C),v(D,A))[0]+  2*CD*crs(v(E,D),v(E,A))[0]
    t=   DE*crs(v(D,C),v(D,E))[0]
    Y[0]=(x *C[0]+y*D[0]+z*E[0]+t*A[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    Y[1]=(x *C[1]+y*D[1]+z*E[1]+t*A[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    #Here to calculate C_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   EA*crs(v(A,E),v(A,B))[0]
    y=  -EA*crs(v(B,A),v(B,D))[0]+  2*AB*crs(v(E,D),v(E,A))[0]
    z=  -EA*crs(v(E,D),v(E,B))[0]+  2*DE*crs(v(A,E),v(A,B))[0]
    t=   EA*crs(v(E,D),v(E,A))[0]
    Z[0]=(x *D[0]+y*E[0]+z*A[0]+t*B[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    Z[1]=(x *D[1]+y*E[1]+z*A[1]+t*B[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    #Here to calculate D_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   AB*crs(v(B,A),v(B,C))[0]
    y=  -AB*crs(v(C,B),v(C,E))[0]+  2*BC*crs(v(A,E),v(A,B))[0]
    z=  -AB*crs(v(A,E),v(A,C))[0]+  2*EA*crs(v(B,A),v(B,C))[0]
    t=   AB*crs(v(A,E),v(A,B))[0]
    W[0]=(x *E[0]+y*A[0]+z*B[0]+t*C[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    W[1]=(x *E[1]+y*A[1]+z*B[1]+t*C[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    #Here to calculate E_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   BC*crs(v(C,B),v(C,D))[0]
    y=  -BC*crs(v(D,C),v(D,A))[0]+  2*CD*crs(v(B,A),v(B,C))[0]
    z=  -BC*crs(v(B,A),v(B,D))[0]+  2*AB*crs(v(C,B),v(C,D))[0]
    t=   BC*crs(v(B,A),v(B,C))[0]
    T[0]=(x *A[0]+y*B[0]+z*C[0]+t*D[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    T[1]=(x *A[1]+y*B[1]+z*C[1]+t*D[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    A=X
    B=Y
    C=Z
    D=W
    E=T
    print(f"A_{i}= {A}")
    print(f"B_{i}= {B}")
    print(f"C_{i}= {C}")
    print(f"D_{i}= {D}")
    print(f"E_{i}= {E}")
    print("\n")


Another thing that supports the convergence of the series that no matter how many times I used that random function in python with the sequence the result always converge (suggesting it always converge except some zero measure set )

I think 15 pentagons are enough for the example I run out of colors or at least ones that human eye can easily distinguish from.

What measure on the set of pentagon are you referring to?

Did you try the equivalent for triangles and quadrilaterals?

A similar problem relates to nested triangles formed by angle bisectors. The case for the triangle is well-known, but unsolved for the general case.
Years ago, I wrote a short paper (note) for the special case of an isosceles triangle that you may find helpful: Rob Downes, A Recurrence relation for the limit point of nested triangles, Mathematical Gazette, 99 (July 2015), pp. 323-325 I would love to see the general case cracked! Rob

@rob Can you give me a link to your paper?
